# Parametrization curve of intersection

Tags: calculus, parametrization

Consider the interseccion of the surfaces:

$x+y+z=1$ and $x^2+y^2=1$.

I need to parametrize the curve of intersection, and know it is an ellipse on the plane,so  I tried with

$\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,1-\cos t -\sin t),0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

But what I'm not sure about is the eccentricity of the ellipse, I mean, should it be of the following form?

$\gamma(t)=( k\cos t,l\sin t,1-k\cos t -l\sin t)$ with $k,l\in \mathbb{R}$ not necessarily 1?

Comment: The easiest way to check is to plug back into the original equations. You will notice that your first parametrization is correct, whereas the second one with some free parameters does not satisfy either of the equations.

Comment: Sorry @NathanMarianovsky I make a misake, it should be $\gamma (t)=(k\cos t, l\sin t, 1-k\sin t - l\sin t)$.

Comment: Ok so now it will definitely satisfy the plane equation, but not the one for the unit cylinder because you would need: $k^2\cos^2(t) + l^2\sin^2(t) = 1$ which can only occur if $k = l = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb A$ is one of rotational transforms that convert $(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3})$ into $(0,0,1)$.

$\mathbb A=$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt2} & -\frac1{\sqrt2} & 0\\
\frac1{\sqrt6} & \frac1{\sqrt6} & -\frac2{\sqrt6}\\
\frac1{\sqrt3} & \frac1{\sqrt3} & \frac1{\sqrt3}\\
\end{bmatrix}

$\mathbb A$ would transform $\left(\cos t, \sin t, -\cos t-\sin t,0\right)$ [note that I shifted the z coordinate by $-1$ to make things more visible] into
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos t-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin t,\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}\cos t+\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}\ \sin t,0\right)$$

Now let's eliminate the parameter $t$, we substutue

$$x=\frac1{\sqrt2}(\cos t - \sin t)$$
$$y=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}(\cos t + \sin t)$$

And we get this equation

$$\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+\left(x\right)^2=\left(\frac{\cos t - \sin t}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\cos t + \sin t}{\sqrt2}\right)^2=1$$